# How can I iterate over .log files, process them through awk, and replace with output files with different extensions?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sunos

Let's say that we have multiple .log files on the prod unix machine(Sunos) in a directory:
For example:

```
ls -tlr                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
total 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
-rw-r--r-- 1 21922 21922 0 Sep 10 13:15 file2017-01.log                                                                                                                                                                               
-rw-r--r-- 1 21922 21922 0 Sep 10 13:15 file2016-02.log                                                                                                                                                                               
-rw-r--r-- 1 21922 21922 0 Sep 10 13:15 todo2015-01.log                                                                                                                                                                               
-rw-r--r-- 1 21922 21922 0 Sep 10 13:15 fix20150223.log
```

The purpose here is that via nawk I extract specific info from the logs( parse logs ) and "transform" them to .csv files in order to load them to ORACLE tables afterwards.
Although the nawk has been tested and works like a charm, how could I automate a bash script that does the following:

1) For a list of given files in this path

2) nawk (to do my extraction of specific data/info from the log file)

3) Output **separately each file to a unique .csv** to another directory

4) remove the .log files from this path

What does concern me is that the loadstamp/timestamp on each file ending that is different. I have implemented a script that works only for the latest date. (eg. last month). But I want to **load all the historical data** and I am bit stuck.

To visualize, my desired/target output is this:

```
bash-4.4$ ls -tlr                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
total 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
-rw-r--r-- 1 21922 21922 0 Sep 10 13:15 file2017-01.csv                                                                                                                                                                               
-rw-r--r-- 1 21922 21922 0 Sep 10 13:15 file2016-02.csv                                                                                                                                                                               
-rw-r--r-- 1 21922 21922 0 Sep 10 13:15 todo2015-01.csv                                                                                                                                                                               
-rw-r--r-- 1 21922 21922 0 Sep 10 13:15 fix20150223.csv
```

How could this bash script please be achieved? The loading will only takes one time, it's historical as mentioned.
Any help could be extremely useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An implementation written for readability rather than terseness might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for infile in *.log; do
  outfile=${infile%.log}.csv
  if awk -f yourscript <"$infile" >"$outfile"; then
    rm -f -- "$infile"
  else
    echo "Processing of $infile failed" >&2
    rm -f -- "$outfile"
  fi
done
```

---

To understand how this works, see:

- [Globbing](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) -- the mechanism by which `*.log` is replaced with a list of files with that extension.
- [The Classic `for` Loop](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/classic_for) -- The `for infile in` syntax, used to iterate over the results of the glob above.
- [Parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) -- The `${infile%.log}` syntax, used to expand the contents of the `infile` variable with any `.log` suffix pruned.
- [Redirection](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection) -- the syntax used in `<"$infile"` and `>"$outfile"`, opening stdin and stdout attached to the named files; or `>&2`, redirecting logs to stderr. (Thus, when we run `awk`, its stdin is connected to a `.log` file, and its stdout is connected to a `.csv` file).

Comment: Thank you Charles. Can you please explain me the above more detailed?

Also "yourscript" is not clear to me.. My script works only for the latest .log received.

Comment: `yourscript` should be the name of the file containing the tested awk script of which you assert possession in the question.

Comment: But how will this work out? Since it nawks and process only the latest log files.

Comment: @amno, why do you think it does that? It iterates over `*.log` -- that's **every** file matching the pattern.

Comment: @amno, ...if your awk script knows or cares about filenames, then simplify it until it doesn't -- the answer here assumes an awk script that reads from its stdin and writes to its stdout, which is what they do by default. I can't tell you how to change it to no longer do that (ie. exactly what you need to remove to take out the behavior *someone explicitly and intentionally added* for that purpose) unless you provide us the script.

Comment: @amno, ...re: request for explanation, I've edited with links to the relevant syntax. Let me know if there's anything I missed. (And see the update to the code made at the same time).

Comment: Okay Charles, I will study the links and your solution and let you know, thanks a lot for your time and effort!

Comment: Hello, well it is not working as expected.Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154230/mutliple-log-files-nawk-manipulation-and-extract-info

Comment: So, given what you provided there, the file following the `-f` argument should contain `/^Table/{gsub(/.*\.|[\":]/,""); table=$0;next}/Rows successfully loaded/{rows = $1;next}/Run began on/{ sub(/Run began on /,""); start = $0 ;next }/Run ended on/{sub(/Run ended on /,"");print table, rows, start, $0}`. Or you could leave out the `-f` and just put the script text in that position.